# Cannot add canvas with external JS file

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add a canvas to my index.html but it's not working at all. As in it doesn't show up. Here is my index.html and game.js file source. Please help, I've been trying to figure this out for the last hour or so and it still doesn't work. I've tested it in multiple browsers. I'm using brackets as my editor if that helps.

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Dogepet</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center><p>Dogepet</p>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/game.js"></script></center>
    </body>
</html>
```

game.js

```
//Create the canvas
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 612;
canvas.height = 480;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

//Background image
var bgReady = false;
var bgImage = new Image();
bgImage.onload = function () {
    bgReady = true;
};
bgImage.src = "images/dogepark.png";
var doge = {
    speed: 10;
    x: canvas.width/2;
    y: 380;
};

var render = function () {
    if (bgReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);
    }
};

var main = function () {
    render();
};

setInterval(main,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into the Javascript console. In Firefox, I see this error message

> [22:39:46.543] SyntaxError: missing } after property list

After replacing the semicolons `;` with commas `,`, everything works as expected.

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DGEN2/)

Comment: Don't worry, as you gain experience, this will happen less and less often.